# FBlogin Button Customization

Tags: facebook

I had used facebook login button in my website, is there any way to customize the fblogin button because instead of fblogin i want the button as "Link to your Facebook" like this.Please suggest any ideas to get this button customization

I am using the following set of codes for the fblogin button.

FB.init({
    appId  : xxxxxxx,
    status : true, // check login status
    cookie : false, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
    xfbml  : true  // parse XFBML
  });

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using the javascript sdk, you can implement the login yourself (FB.login) and use whatever button you would like. You just need to run the FB.login code in the onclick. If you do that, you are not bound to the facebook generated iframe.

Comment: @Elad.I do need the Facebook generated iframe information for registration so that would not be possible to do i hope.

Comment: @Anandhan - You can do with the JS SDK anything you can do through the iframe, and it allows much more flexability. It just depends on your needs and how badly you want to change the button image.

Comment: @Elad.I don't have much experience with the JS SDK, so could you please provide any reference link to make like that which will be helpful for me to understand the concepts.

Comment: http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/ You will first need to load the script and then init the connection with facebook. Then you can use the FB.login method to do the actual login and request permissions as needed.

Comment: @Elad.Thanks for your valuable ideas.

Comment: @Anandhan - Happy to help. It takes some time to get your head around the JS SDK, but once you do, you can do anything Facebook related in your site. I have even reproduced a client's page wall on their site.

Comment: @Elad: You are great and happy to know about this. I will read out the things step by step because my next task is going to post my site users interest to his FB friends wall.

Answer (score 0):

In the case of the javascript sdk mentioned above the actual implementation would look something like this:

```
<fb:login-button scope="email, user_birthday, user_likes" onlogin="showWelcomeMessage()">Link to your Facebook</fb:login-button>
```

There's an onlogin event you can use to call a function once the user logs in eg `showWelcomeMessage()`

or

```
<div class="fb-login-button" data-scope="email" data-show-faces="true" data-width="200" data-max-rows="1">Link to your Facebook</div>
```

All the data attributes listed are optional

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// Code to handle login
</script>
```

It's the text inside of the elements that counts, and you can imagine using an image if desired as well.

As an aside, you'll want to keep up to date with Facebook and it's rapid changes:
https://developers.facebook.com/roadmap/

Resources:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/login/